# How to Vertically Justify Items Over the Textheight of the Previous Page After Using \newpage

Tags: spacing, page-breaking, description, vertical-spacing, justification

The following code

```
\documentclass{book}
\textheight 5.25in
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}

    \begin{document}
    \large
    \begin{description}
    \item \lipsum[13]
    
    \item \lipsum[13]
    
    \item \lipsum[13]
    
    \item A sentence.
    
    \item A sentence.
    
    %\newpage
    \item \lipsum[13]
    
    \item \lipsum[1]
    
    \item \lipsum[1]
    
    \item \lipsum[1]
    
    \item \lipsum[1]
    \end{description}
    \end{document}
```

produces (first two pages displayed) the output:

[image]

In the actual document, for the most part, I don't mind the items being split across two pages; however, every once in a while (such as for the sixth item in the MWE), I don't want that to happen. So, in this case, if I run the code with `\newpage` immediately before the sixth item, I get

[image]

QUESTION: For the first page only in the MWE (but on demand, as needed, in the actual document), how may I vertically spread out the first five items so that they evenly extend over the entire height of the page? I don't want to use something like  `\setlength\itemsep{1em plus 1fil} \interlinepenalty=10000` for that might cause large gaps in subsequent pages because the items will not be permitted to break across pages.

Thank you.

Comment: `\newpage` is like `\newline` and leaves the page short, you want `\pagebreak` which is like `\linebreak` which just forces a break at that point.

Comment: @David Carlisle Thank you kindly for pointing this out.